# Trying to create a Burndown chart on Power BI for the number of features! Issue with remaining features line

Tags: powerbi, dax, burndowncharts

Need the Remaining Features Line to stop on current date and not extend throughout. Also it should start with total number of features and reduce as and when the features are moved to closed.

Formulaes:
*1)  Works as expected
*2) **Has an issue**
*3) Works fine
*4) Works fine

1)

```
 Planned Completion Count = 
VAR TotalFeatures = 
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            'Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard', 
            'Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard'[Work Item Type] = "Feature" &&
            'Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard'[State] <> "Removed" &&
            'Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard'[Phase] = "MVPCashFlow"
        )
    )
VAR StartDate = DATE(2023, 8, 1)
VAR MaxPlannedClosingDate = MAX('Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard'[Planned Closing Date])
VAR TotalDays = MaxPlannedClosingDate - StartDate
VAR FeaturesPerDay = DIVIDE(TotalFeatures, TotalDays)
VAR DaysPassed = MAX('Calendar'[Date]) - StartDate
RETURN
IF(
    DaysPassed >= 0 && DaysPassed <= TotalDays,
    ROUND(TotalFeatures - FeaturesPerDay * DaysPassed, 0),
    BLANK()
)
```

2. Remaining Features Line =
   VAR TotalFeatures = [Total Features]
   VAR PlannedCount = [Planned Completion Count]
   VAR ActualCount = [Actual Completion Count]
   VAR CurrentDate = TODAY()
   VAR RemainingCount = TotalFeatures - ActualCount
   VAR DaysPassed = MAX('Calendar'[Date]) - DATE(2023, 8, 1)
   RETURN
   IF(
   DaysPassed >= 0,
   PlannedCount - IF(DaysPassed = 0, 0, ROUND(RemainingCount / DaysPassed * CurrentDate, 0)),
   BLANK()
   )
3. Remaining Features Line =
   VAR TotalFeatures = [Total Features]
   VAR PlannedCount = [Planned Completion Count]
   VAR ActualCount = [Actual Completion Count]
   VAR CurrentDate = TODAY()
   VAR RemainingCount = TotalFeatures - ActualCount
   VAR DaysPassed = MAX('Calendar'[Date]) - DATE(2023, 8, 1)
   RETURN
   IF(
   DaysPassed >= 0,
   PlannedCount - IF(DaysPassed = 0, 0, ROUND(RemainingCount / DaysPassed * CurrentDate, 0)),
   BLANK()
   )
4. [image: Total Features = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard'), FILTER( 'Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard', 'Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard'[Work Item Type] = "Feature" && 'Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard'[State] <> "Removed" && 'Compustat Transformation - ADO Dashboard'[Phase] = "MVPCashFlow" ) )]